# get Row Number for R data frame

Tags: r

A question about data frames in R.  I want to extract a row from a data frame, along with its position(row number) in the original data frame. The idea is to create a new data frame that includes the row information extracted from the previous data frame, as well as the row position from the previous data frame.

```
patchLocalNo <- patchList[which(patchListTop5$sensitivity == patchLocalSpec),]
```

what I want to do is take the row numbers from patchList that satisfy the which condition, and add them to a column in patchLocalNo.

Thank you in advance, I have searched online and asked co-workers and all I can come up with is a work-around pre-processing the data in perl.

Comment: Some sample data and an example of the output you would like would be very helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question.

The results of which() is a vector with the row numbers that you want to extract.

```
df <- data.frame(x = runif(20))

w <- which(df$x > 0.9)
w
[1]  9 11 14 16 20

data.frame(which=w, df=df[w, ])

  which        df
1     9 0.9437138
2    11 0.9995509
3    14 0.9237888
4    16 0.9526003
5    20 0.9191727
```

Comment: The OP is looking to match the whole row, not just a single value, and wants to append the row number to the retrieved values...

Comment: @Benjamin  That might well be the case, alhough it's not entirely clear from the question.  In any case, my example code will do this - identify the row number of the data frame that matches the boolean statement, and appends this to the extracted row.  Without a better specification of the problem, and some sample data, I can't think of an obvious way of improving the answer.

Comment: the solution provided works for my script, " identify the row number of the data frame that matches the boolean statement, and appends this to the extracted row" is exactly what this solution does.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one or two lines of code:

```
rNo <- as.integer(rownames(patchList[which(patchListTop5$sensitivity == patchLocalSpec),]))
patchLocalNo <- cbind(patchLocalNo[rNames,], rNo)
```