# How do I count the number of observations at given intervals in R?

Tags: r

I have data which includes variables for the hour, the minute, and the second for each observation. I want to count the number of observations before 3am, all observations before 6am,  all observations before 9am and so on. Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.

Example of the data:

```
day    hour    minute   second
01       17        10       03
01       17        14       20
01       17        25       27
01       17        32       39
01       17        33       40
01       17        34       10
01       17        34       14
01       17        34       16
01       17        34       21
01       17        34       23
01       17        34       25
01       17        34       31
01       17        34       36
```

I have about 300,000 observations like this.

hour  : int  17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17

minute: int  10 14 25 32 33 34 34 34 34 34

second: int  3 20 27 39 40 10 14 16 21 23

Comment: Hi there, I have suggested this question be moved to Stack Overflow. Regardless of where it sits, could you please provide some of your data values in your question and also a `str()` output on your data, for the time variable in particular.

Comment: If my edit to your question is accepted, you will see your data laid out in columns in your question, I hope that is okay - I laid it out that way for clarity.

Comment: that is way better! thank you so much. Did you use markdown to do that?

Comment: Sort of. I haven't worked out how to do all markdown efficiently, so some  of it I do manually. :)

Comment: Either way, I really appreciate it. And thanks for suggesting this be moved! One random question - do you know how to create a variable in R that just tells you which row an observation is? In stata, you just use _n but I dont know the R equivalent. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269624/how-to-get-row-from-r-dataframe or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553802/get-row-number-for-r-data-frame

Comment: Thanks for the links! I had a read of them and they do indeed answer the question I had asked above. Unfortunately, this is because I had worded that question badly! Say you have data with 10 rows. And you want to generate a variable that equals 1 for row 1, 2 for row 2...and 10 for row 10. Is that easily done in R? Sorry for wasting your time before.

Comment: Not to worry. I worked out the answer! So basic in hindsight. data$number <- 1:300000 (assuming I have 300,000 rows). Thanks so much for your answers yesterday.

Comment: `1:nrow(data)` is a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 7):

One approach is to create a new variable based on your binning criteria, then tabulate on that variable:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(hour = sample(0:23, 100, TRUE, prob = runif(24)),
                  minute = sample(0:59,100, TRUE, prob = runif(60)),
                  second = sample(0:59,100, TRUE, prob = runif(60)))

#Adjust bins accordingly
dat <- transform(dat, bin = ifelse(hour < 3,"Before 3",
                                   ifelse(hour < 6,"Before 6",
                                          ifelse(hour <9,"Before 9","Later in day"))))

as.data.frame(table(dat$bin))
          Var1 Freq
1     Before 3    7
2     Before 6   17
3     Before 9   19
4 Later in day   57
```

Depending on the number of bins you need, you may run into issues with the nested ifelse() statements, but that should give you a start. Update your question with more details if you get stuck.

Comment: Note that `cut()` is often used for the binning exercise I just went through above. That would be my next place to stop.

Comment: Chase, This was really helpful. Really appreciate you answering my question!

Comment: Cut would be my first choice: it just feels easier, `table(cut(dat$hour, seq(0,24,3)))`

Answer (score 3):

How about  `length(which(data$hour <=2 ))`  ?  I used 2 o'clock here to avoid having to deal with minutes and seconds in the first place.  Then loop or `apply` over all the different hours you want to count.

If you need to restart your count every day, then make use of the data$day value similarly.

Comment: Carl, thanks for answering my question. As a noob, this was the first approach I used to make sure I could actually get the data I want. I then went and used the method Chase taught so it was good to learn more tricks! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

This approach gives you more flexibility if you decide you need different times.  You can find n below any time point (not just hours).  Because I'm lazy I made this work treating everything as characters.

```
#1.  Create a fake data set as chase did
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(hour = sample(0:23, 100, TRUE, prob = runif(24)),
                  minute = sample(0:59,100, TRUE, prob = runif(60)),
                  second = sample(0:59,100, TRUE, prob = runif(60)))

#2.  Create a function to turn your single digits double and everything into character 
dig <- function(x){ 
    ifelse(nchar(as.character(x))<2, paste("0", as.character(x), sep=""),
        as.character(x))
}

#3.  Use the dig function to make a character dataframe    
dat <- data.frame(sapply(dat, dig))

#4.  Paste hour minute and second together into new character vector
dat <- transform(dat, time=as.numeric(paste(hour, minute, second,sep="")))

#5.  function to take that character vector and compare it to the cut off time    
n.obs <- function(var, hour='0', min='00', sec='00', pm=FALSE){
    hour <- if(pm) as.character(as.numeric(hour) + 12) else hour
    bench <- as.numeric(paste(hour, min, sec, sep=""))
    length(var[var<=bench])
}

#try it out
n.obs(dat$time, '2')
n.obs(dat$time, '2', pm=T)
n.obs(dat$time, '14', pm=F)  #notice same as above because pm=F
n.obs(dat$time, hour='14', min='30', pm=F)
```